# How do I back up via FTP and rsync?

Tags: rsync

I am new to these backup things. I have try Backuppc and rsnashot. Backuppc was cool, with web frontend.

My probleam: 
I don't have any backup servers I just have server and ftp-disk. I wanted to backup my server to ftp-disk, but I'm not sure how to do it? Can I use rsync?

Comment: I think this post has exactly what you want: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools

Comment: What do you mean "ftp-disk"?

Answer (score 6):

Another solution, if you have lftp:

```
lftp -e "mirror -R src_local_folder dest_folder_on_ftp_server; exit" -u ftp_user[,ftp_pass] ftp_server
```

Support SSL/TLS

Answer (score 3):

`rsync` works over ssh, but not over FTP. Full discussion here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/24622/how-to-use-rsync-over-ftp

(Short answer in case serverfault ever goes down: you can't. Try `lftp`.)

Answer (score 3):

you can mount the ftp resource as a local

```
curlftpfs [user@]host:[dir] mountpoint [options]
```

and use rsync as to local directories

Answer (score 1):

Little script for that that can be useful, mirror a local directory to distant with given configuration @ beginning of script

```
#!/bin/bash
#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
#
#       DESCRIPTION: Mirrors local site and remote site
#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
FTP_HOST=aFtpHost.org
FTP_USER=YourUserHere
FTP_PWD=yourPasswdHere
LOCAL_SOURCE_PATH=/home/myName/locations/music/${1} #param 1 from script for example
REMOTE_DEST_PATH=/htdocs/aDirectory

EXCLUDE_FILES_LIST=".svn empty anotherDirectory"

# Construct excludes
for exclude in ${EXCLUDE_FILES_LIST}; do
EXCLUDES="-x ${exclude} ${EXCLUDES}"
done

# -R, --reverse       reverse mirror (put files)
# mirror -e
#--delete        delete files not present at remote site
lftp ftp://${FTP_USER}:${FTP_PWD}@${FTP_HOST} -e "mirror ${EXCLUDES} -R ${LOCAL_SOURCE_PATH} ${REMOTE_DEST_PATH} ; quit"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution you might want to look into is a package called `backup-manager` (http://www.backup-manager.org/).

This is a great script and lets you leverage multiple back up methods. Rsync, SSH, FTP, and even Amazon S3. Very simple to configure and you

You can do a `aptitude search backup-manager` to get more information

Comment: Link goes to a Chinese page